# Aggregate function in R not working with POSIXct

Tags: r

I'd like to aggregate my data.

```
time<- as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-10 00:11:02","2014-12-10 00:11:02","2014-12-10 00:11:03"), tz= "GMT")
shares<-c(1,2,3)
price<-c(48, 48, 49)
dat<-data.frame(time= as.factor(time), price= price, size =shares)
dat
```

here is what dat looks like:

```
             time price size
1 2014-12-10 00:11:02    48    1
2 2014-12-10 00:11:02    48    2
3 2014-12-10 00:11:03    49    3
```

now I try to aggregate dat

```
aggregate(x=dat, by = list( as.factor(dat$size)), formula = cbind(dat$time, dat$price) ~ as.numeric(dat$size), FUN="sum")
```

I want to aggregate the shares column in dat across time and price so it looks like this:

```
time                  price  size
2014-12-10 00:11:02    48    3
2014-12-10 00:11:03    49    3
```

any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: You should avoid using cbind on vectors of different class. Furthermore you were getting the order of the RHS and the LHS backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
aggregate(x = dat$size, by = list(time, price), FUN = "sum")

              Group.1 Group.2 x
1 2014-12-10 00:11:02      48 3
2 2014-12-10 00:11:03      49 3
```

Or

```
aggregate(size ~ time + price, data = dat, FUN = "sum")

                 time price size
1 2014-12-10 00:11:02    48    3
2 2014-12-10 00:11:03    49    3
```

These correspond to the docs for `?aggregate`, which give possible forms:

```
aggregate(x, by, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE)
aggregate(formula, data, FUN, ..., subset, na.action = na.omit)
```

Your attempt mixed these forms up together.

Comment: it is a matter of taste, I like dplyr as alternative `dat %>% group_by(time,price) %>% summarise(size = sum(size))`

Comment: Indeed, but the question was "Aggregate function in R not working...".